# Not able to compile exoplayer in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have imported exoplayer using jcenter but am getting error as :
Error:(46, 13) Failed to resolve:   com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.3.0
Following is my code of gradles:

### build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript{
repositories {
    jcenter()
   /* mavenCentral()*/
}
dependencies{
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc1'
 // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
 // in the individual module build.gradle files
}}allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete)
{
 delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### build.gradle(Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.pash.dr"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}} 
 repositories {
     jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
}
dependencies
{
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
/** *************For player ***************/
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.3.0'
}
```

Please guide me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: whats the error you are getting.

Comment: Error:(46, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.3.0

Answer (score 2):

Change exo player dependencies to 1.5.2 and then go to **File->Invalidate cache /restart**

```
dependencies
{
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
/** *************For player ***************/
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.2'
}
```

Comment: shall i add external jar for it..? It will work for me..?

Comment: yep that's a great idea. do it like that.

Comment: Right now getting                                                                                Could not resolve com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.3.1.
Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer/r2.3.1/exoplayer-r2.3.1.pom'.
Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer/r2.3.1/exoplayer-r2.3.1.pom'.
Remote host closed connection during handshake

Comment: This may be due to connection issue or may be some files missing in :exoplayer:r2.3.1. Just download the external jar file exoplayer:r1.5.2 and add it to the project. then try rebuilding

Comment: Thank's bro for your needful helf ..it's firwall issue..:)

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to go back in versions, 
you can use the last release version: as in this link [1]https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/releases
just try to do invalidate and restart your project

Comment: I have used r2.3.1 which is latest version and invalidate restart project still getting same error

Comment: that's strange.. maybe try to clean the project, and also try to remove this player dependency, maybe something else causing this problem... good luck ;)

Comment: Nope when i remove player dependency project build successfully..:)

Comment: Thank's bro for your needful helf ..it's firwall issue..:)