# Android studio com.google.android.exoplayer2 does not exist error

Tags: android, android-studio

I download an app source code from GitHub and when I open the project on android studio it shows error and ([Not able to compile exoplayer in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512379/not-able-to-compile-exoplayer-in-android-studio)) I also read and try this StackOverflow answer but it didn't solve my issue

```
error: package com.google.android.exoplayer2 does not exist
```

and also build output error

[image]

build.gradle(module: app) code

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "tabian.com.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
    }

    dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//Design library for Coordinator Layout and Toolbars
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
//ExifInterface support
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
//design library for Coordinator Layout
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
//Exo Player
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.2'
//cardview
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
//recyclerview
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
//BottomNavigationViewEx library
implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.1.9'
//Circle ImageView
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
//elastic header
implementation 'com.github.eschao:android-ElasticListView:v1.0'
//material dialogs
implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
//glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
implementation files('libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3 (1).jar')
//Universal image loader
implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
//firebase authentication
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
//firebase database
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.6'
//firebase storage
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.6'
implementation files('libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3 (1).jar')
   }

    //Firebase
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.2'
```

with the current version:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.5'
```

It's available from either the `google()` or the `jcenter()` repository.

Comment: One simple request can you please upvote my question so that I gain some reputation

Comment: Just in case someone is looking for com.google.android.exoplayer (without 2 at the end) - do the reverse thing. Replace `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.5'` with `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.2'`

I had an issue with Tv App because of using exoplayer2 version ;-)

Comment: hey After adding AppLovin SDK it says  Cannot resolve symbol 'ExoPlayerFactory'

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;

Already used latest and jcenter (). Without AppLovin SDK its work fine